# Selenium getting href link returning null

Tags: selenium, href

Getting href link from following html is always giving me null. I have been trying multiple ways to get this I cannot use xpath since xpath changes for every page.

```
<div class="form-group" id="idfb">
    <label class="control-label">PDF </label>&nbsp; <a type="button" value="Download" href="./decisiondecisionForm-pdfContainer-filePdfDownload&amp;id=6303"><i class="fa fa-download fa-2x xh-highlight" aria-hidden="true"></i></a><br>
</div>
```

I am trying to get href in following way

```
val element =  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("*[id^='id']"))
val link = element.getAttribute("href")
```

Is issue in aria-hidden attribute ?

Comment: Can you please provide a link to this page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this: Assuming  div class="form-group" id="idfb">

is parent tag.

```
val element =  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("*[id^='id' a]"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you want get the href attribute from the `<a>` tag, and your selector is not referring to it, but to the `div` tag.

The `div` tag doesn't have the href attribute, so that's why your code returns null.

So, instead you can try with the following value: **`By.cssSelector("div[id^='id'] > a")`**